# Top-bar submenu is not working in mobile view foundation

Tags: html, css, mobile, zurb-foundation, submenu

I've been using foundation for my latest projects, but I never had this problem before. The submenu is not working on mobile view, but it is working for browser view.

This is the site url https://www.kimonoboy.com/about_us_testpage.html if you reduce the page width you'll see that the submenu is not showing.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Comment: THANKS! for fixing my question, I wasn't aware that there is a format for asking questions in stackoverflow, I was just trying to be polite, have a great day.

Answer (score 0):

In `foundation.min.css:1996` class `.top-bar-section .dropdown` see the `left:100%` it's okay for large screen.
but in small screen your menu tab getting full width, so your sub menu hides behind the left side.

**Solution :** remove `left:100%` for small screen

Comment: thanks for your response @Sachink, I found out there was an issue with a js file that was crashing the foundation.js execution.